# Android Studio NDK Library Project: Gradle Build Error "The Specified File does not exist"

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

**SOLVED**

Use the following command

```
gradlew build [options]
```

Instead of

```
gradlew -build [options]
```

It basically thought **-build** was the declaration of an option argument and not a call to the **build** task.

I have merely overseen this, but am going to leave this question here In case anyone makes the same mistake.

**The Problem:**

Gradle build process failed with IllegalArgumentException: The specified build file '**\uild**' does not exist.

**Background:**

I am writing a shared libray for android using Android NDK to make use of in the Unity Game Engine. I have had several iteration cycles where everything went as expected (that is a new build was created and being tested in Unity). I have written some code over the last few days and even left my computer on over night.

Today I return to the project and press the UI's "Build" (green hammer) button. Everything seems to work, but the output files in my build directory are not updated. I wonder what causes this isse and run the gradle build process via terminal using the following command:

```
gradlew -build --debug --info --stacktrace
```

**What happens:**

The process starts and crashes, returning the following (relevant) log:

```
22:09:43.479 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
22:09:43.479 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
22:09:43.479 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
22:09:43.479 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
22:09:43.479 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] The specified build file 'E:\Android_Development\NDK_Libraries\UnityOboe\uild' does not exist.
22:09:43.479 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
```

Everything before this seems to be unlrelated to this issue.

**Notes**

The only [issue I found, that resembles my error most](https://github.com/shadowsocks/shadowsocks-android/issues/1575) is related to a different project and has a completely different background as well. Unfortunately I can't even provide any steps to reproduce this error.

If there is the need for me to provide additional information (build files, etc.) I'll do so. The problem is that I didn't change a thing except for some code in a .cpp file and tried to get a new build (I didn't even turn the computer of let alone close android studio).

A restart of both Android Studio and my computer also did not resolve the issue.

At this point I just can't draw any connections so I'm pretty lost.

Comment: Try 'invalidate caches and Restart' option from 'File' tab in android studio. and if it does not work share the log.

Comment: @RanjanKumar it worked one time but I did not do anything. Now the same error is occuring again. I did what you suggessted but it didn't change the result. I edited my post to show the full log at the end of it. Your - and anybody elses - help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this location exist and where are you referring this location in your project? Is it possible to share build.gradle and app/build.gradle?

Comment: @RanjanKumar the problem was the syntax I used to execute the command, see the top Header of the question for clarification. Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

Use the following command

```
gradlew build [options]
```

Instead of

```
gradlew -build [options]
```

It basically thought **-build** was the declaration of an option argument and not a call to the **build** task.

I have merely overseen this, but am going to leave this question here In case anyone makes the same mistake.